# Problem in mysql database!

Tags: mysql, mariadb, running-totals

how to create a view of this query in (mysql) database.

```
SET @variable = 0;
-- Without Pagination
SELECT
    id,
   `credit`,
   `debit`,
    @variable := @variable + (`credit` - `debit`) `Balance`
FROM          tbl_total
ORDER BY      id ASC;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use a recent enough version* of MariaDB, you can use window functions instead of variables to get a running total:

```
-- CREATE VIEW
--     running_total AS
SELECT
    id, credit, debit, 
    SUM(credit-debit) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS balance
FROM
    tbl_total
ORDER BY
    id ;
```

You can create a view with the above query.

*: Window functions are available since [MariaDB version 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/) and in [MySQL version 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html).

Comment: Did the user knew he had window functions available? I would suggest to indicate the versions the functionality started working (10.2 and 8.0 if I remember correctly).

Comment: ":@jynus thanx. Answer edited, with links.